Spring app returns 401 in route when I request with Postman, but returns ok when I request with Integration Test
Before talk about the problem, I need to clarify some points:

The route needs authentication
The route doesn't need any role

I have a controller to receive, retrieve and update static files:
package com.adoula.doulasapi.controller;

import com.adoula.doulasapi.enums.DocumentType;
import com.adoula.doulasapi.model.file.Document;
import com.adoula.doulasapi.service.DocumentService;
import com.adoula.doulasapi.service.ImageService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/static")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class StaticController {

    private final ImageService imageService;
    private final DocumentService documentService;

    @GetMapping("/public/logos/{fileName}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getLogo(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName){
        return imageService.getLogo(fileName);
    }

    @PutMapping("/images/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleImageUpload(@RequestParam("image")MultipartFile file){
        return imageService.save( file);
    }
    @GetMapping("/images/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getImage(@PathVariable("id") UUID imageId){
        return imageService.getImageById(imageId);
    }
    @GetMapping("/images/my")
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleWhenUserRequestSelfImage(){
        return imageService.getPerfilImage();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/images/my/delete")
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleWhenUserRequestDeletePerfilImage(){
        return imageService.handleWhenUserRequestDeletePerfilImage();
    }


    @PutMapping("/docs/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<?> handledocsUpload(
            @RequestParam("document")MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam("docType")DocumentType type
            ){
        return documentService.save(file, type);
    }
    @GetMapping("/docs/{docId}")
    @Secured({"ADMIN"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> getDocs(@PathVariable("docId")UUID docId){
        return documentService.getOneDocument(docId);
    }

    @GetMapping("/docs/my")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Document>> handleFindAllMyDocuments(){
        return documentService.findAllDocumentsFromAssociada();
    }
}

The route that i'm having problem its the **PUT /api/v1/static/images/upload
**
I have some tests to test this put route, and here an example:
   @Test
    @DisplayName("Should update my image")
    public void shouldUpdateMyImage() throws Exception {
        //Arrange
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/test/resources/images/doula2.jpg"));
        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile(
                "image",
                "doula2.jpg",
                "image/jpeg", fileContent);

        //Act
        this.mockMvc.perform(
                        MockMvcRequestBuilders
                                .multipart(HttpMethod.PUT,baseUrl + "/images/upload")
                                .file(file)
                                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.expiredAssociadaAuthToken)
                                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
                )
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(result -> {
                    String responseBody = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
                    Assertions.assertNotNull(responseBody);

                    //Convert response body to uuid
                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    UUID uuid = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, UUID.class);

                    //check if profilePhoto exists
                    ProfilePhoto profilePhoto = profilePhotoRepository.findById(uuid).orElseThrow();
                    Assertions.assertNotNull(profilePhoto);

                    //check if file exists
                    String filePath = profilePhoto.getPath();
                    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(Paths.get(filePath)));
                });
    }

When I run this test, I don't have any problema with authentication:
Test Result
But if I try to send with Postman, it returns 401:
Postman error print
(Here is authentication):
Bearer auth print
Here is my SecurityConfig:
package com.adoula.doulasapi.config;

import com.adoula.doulasapi.security.filter.JwtFilter;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/associadas/list").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/associadas/{id}").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(
                        "/api/v1/account/create",
                        "/api/v1/account/recover-password-request",
                        "/api/v1/account/change-password",
                        "/api/v1/account/activate/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(
                        "/api/v1/static/public/logos/**",
                        "/api/v1/static/images/{id}",
                        "/api/v1/static/images/my",
                        "/api/v1/static/qrcode/{id}",
                        "/api/v1/static/qrcode/my")
                    .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/v1/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
                    (
                        (request, response, authException) ->
                        {
                            if (authException.getCause() instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
                                // Usuário autenticado, mas sem a role necessária, retorna 403
                                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Forbidden");
                            }

                            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
                        }
                    ));
        return http.build();
    }
}

Here is my JWTServiceImpl:
package com.adoula.doulasapi.service.implementation;

import com.adoula.doulasapi.dto.doula.GetDoulaDTO;
import com.adoula.doulasapi.model.Associada;
import com.adoula.doulasapi.model.User;
import com.adoula.doulasapi.dto.associada.GetAssociadaDto;
import com.adoula.doulasapi.service.JwtService;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Service
public class JwtServiceImpl implements JwtService {

    @Value("${SECRET_KEY}")
    private String SECRET_KEY;

    @Override
    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    private <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> getSubject) {
        final var claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return getSubject.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignKey() {
        var keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

    @Override
    public String generateToken(Associada associada) {
    
        return generateToken(getExtraClaims(associada), new User(associada));
    }
    private HashMap<String, Object> getExtraClaims(Associada associada){
        var extraClaims = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        GetAssociadaDto dto = new GetAssociadaDto(associada);
            extraClaims.put("user", dto);

            if (associada.getPerfilDoula() != null) {
                GetDoulaDTO doulaDTO = new GetDoulaDTO(associada.getPerfilDoula());
                extraClaims.put("doula", doulaDTO);
            }

        return extraClaims;
    }

    private String generateToken(HashMap<String, Object> extraclaims, UserDetails userDetails) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(extraclaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000*60*60*10))
                .signWith(getSignKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTokenValid(String jwt, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(jwt);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(jwt);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }
}


And here is my JWTFilter:
package com.adoula.doulasapi.security.filter;

import com.adoula.doulasapi.exceptions.InvalidTokenException;
import com.adoula.doulasapi.service.JwtService;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;


import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService service;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;


//        se o header for  nulo ou o token do header nao iniciar com 'Bearer '
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            return;
        }

        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);

        try {
            userEmail = service.extractUsername(jwt);

            if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
                if (service.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails,
                            null,
                            userDetails.getAuthorities()
                    );
                    authenticationToken.setDetails(
                            new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                    );

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                }
            }
        }catch (ExpiredJwtException expiredJwtException){
            throw new InvalidTokenException("Token expirado");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}


On my securityConfig class, I get this exception:
enter image description here
When I try to request with routes that doesn't need authentication, I get ok, and when I request to routes that needs authentication, I also get 200. But on this controller returns 401.
I'm trying with various jwt tokens, but it always returning 401. When I decode JWT, I get something like this:
{
  "doula": {
    "id": "444fd068-448e-4d8f-9004-ca479f7596df",
    "cidadeAtuante": "Cielândia",
    "estadoAtuante": "DF",
    "instagram": "doulinhaCeilandia",
    "formacoes": [],
    "deAcordoComOsTermos": true,
    "pontuacao": null,
    "afirmacao": null,
    "associada": {
      "id": "f780e258-2273-45ea-b6cc-fd9f8fce5e64",
      "nome": "Vitor",
      "sobrenome": "Correa",
      "email": "Correa123@gmail.com",
      "dataDeNascimento": [
        2003,
        9,
        11
      ],
      "enderecos": [
        {
          "id": "c5c30845-6ebb-4bc4-b5e4-1f99b2901ca3",
          "l1": "rua correa",
          "l2": "0",
          "l3": "casa correa"
        }
      ],
      "contatos": [],
      "roles": [
        {
          "id": "2a99688f-eebe-4814-9922-c1d9f86c828a",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "name": "ADMIN"
        },
        {
          "id": "a7a2639f-c815-4be4-96bf-d0b4445967c8",
          "deletedAt": null,
          "name": "USER"
        }
      ],
      "cpf": null
    },
    "doulaStatus": "APPROVED"
  },
  "user": {
    "id": "f780e258-2273-45ea-b6cc-fd9f8fce5e64",
    "nome": "Vitor",
    "sobrenome": "Correa",
    "email": "Correa123@gmail.com",
    "dataDeNascimento": [
      2003,
      9,
      11
    ],
    "enderecos": [
      {
        "id": "c5c30845-6ebb-4bc4-b5e4-1f99b2901ca3",
        "l1": "rua correa",
        "l2": "0",
        "l3": "casa correa"
      }
    ],
    "contatos": [],
    "roles": [
      {
        "id": "2a99688f-eebe-4814-9922-c1d9f86c828a",
        "deletedAt": null,
        "name": "ADMIN"
      },
      {
        "id": "a7a2639f-c815-4be4-96bf-d0b4445967c8",
        "deletedAt": null,
        "name": "USER"
      }
    ],
    "cpf": null
  },
  "sub": "Correa123@gmail.com",
  "iat": 1715549464,
  "exp": 1715585464
}

Apparently my exp its ok
